# mvc .net ADO>NET provider is either not registered or could not be loaded

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, firebird

I'm trying to create a web front end to an existing product, which uses a firebird database as the backend.

I've installed the firebird entity framework and data provider nuget packages, but I'm getting this error.

Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded.

I've got the following in the webconfig:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
</providers>
```

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

If someone could point out the probably blatantly obvious thing I'm doing wrong, that would be awesome.

Comment: Do you have "System.Data.dll" exist in the system, and referenced in the project?

Comment: That XML of your web.config doesn't seem to be well-formed, make sure it is actually properly defined. Also make sure you actually have the Firebird ado.net client and Firebird entity framework support referenced in your project.

Comment: The thing is that the error does not keep the web app from running. The web app is still able to read information from the database when its running. The error only occurs when I do things like attempt to generate a code first model from the database / view an existing

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. the installer seems to have botched a reference in the machine.config file. Deleted it and added what was included in the readme file of the firebird DDEX

Comment: this is a [known issue with the installer](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-560) for years